# Which Times Series Database framework for Python is best for portfolio optimization project?

Tags: programming, time-series, portfolio-optimization, database

I am starting to build a portfolio optimization algorithm in Python and want to structure a database to manipulate financial data. Although I have Python experience, I have never used SQL or such database language.

Considering I need to store 10-year-long registries of stocks information, what database framework that can be integrated with Python would you recommend for me to use?

I will need a read-only database that will be updated daily with around 400 stocks in the database.

Comment: Hi and welcome! There are already a number of questions on this here on Quant SE. Did they help? Also: what are your Data Access patterns (read/write patterns) and what is your data frequency (daily? Per minute? Tick data?)

Comment: ...also how many stocks do you need to track?

Comment: I was hoping that someone could suggest me a framework that is suitable for a beginner, that's why I created a new post. The other posts on this subject seemed a bit advanced for me.

Comment: Regarding data access, I will need to read-only. I will update the database daily and we will have around 400 stocks in the database.

Comment: Kdb was designed for time series data but it can be expensive for a license. How granular are the time intervals for each of these stocks?

Comment: I would need a free to use database. It's a college project. Regarding the granularity, I will be working with daily stock prices.

Comment: I can recommend https://questdb.io/ which was is an open source alternative to kdb which was mentioned above. (disclosure: I write the docs for this project)